# AWS instance outgoing traffic

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services

Let's assume I have the following architecture 
1 WEB LB -> connected to -> 2 WEB Instances -> connected to -> APP LB -> connected to -> APP Instances -> connected to -> DB LB -> connected to -> DB Instances.

It's easy to know looking at the LB at each level which instances assigned to it.
my problem is to get from looking at the instances to which LB they are going...

Is it possible to get this info using some kind of API request(I looked and couldn't find anything, maybe I'm missing it) I thought about ssh each instance and run netstat and figure it out from netstat output.

Is there another way to get this info? I'm managing multiple aws account and doing it manually is really hard when I'm trying to troubleshoot stuff, not to mention that I don't always know what is installed on each instance and really would like to have a solution where I don't care :-)

Thanks
Ronen

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?  What do you try to achieve ?  I understand you want to know from which load balancer the instance receive traffic but in your question you mention only one LB per layer.  Please clarify, Thanks

Comment: I will try to clarify, it's easy to know whice instances attached to which LB, you can see it in the LB details and you can query it using API. in some architecture the instances i.e. App servers (let's assume tomcat) are configured to reach/communicate with DB LB, in this case you can't use API to get these details and you can't see it in the instance configuration, this is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: But then, in the DB LB configuration, you can see what instances are served by that LB... the 'describe-load-balancers' API will return - amongst other things - the list of instances served by the load balancer.  You can issue that call on your APP (tomcat) LB or on your DB LB.  I still does not get your point :-)

Comment: so first yes, you can easily tell the instances, each LB serves, WEB LB serves apache web servers, APP LB serve tomcat servers. The communication channel will be as follows, Internet -> apache lb -> apache server -> tomcat lb -> tomcat server, the problem I'm trying to solve is finding a way to identify the connection between apache server and tomcat lb.

Comment: what's the purpose ?  Security group config ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to determine what LB an instance is receiving traffic from.  If this is really a problem you need to solve, use tags to identify what LB the instance is receiving traffic from.